# Scanning in two different characters, and integers, need to print all at once

Tags: c

I'm trying to read in `n`, and on n subsequent there will be a prompt to scan in a number and a string, i.e. "`7 dwarf`" just like baseball names, you know "`30 Rodriguez`" however of course as you can see within my code, it will print, and then prompt another scanf, for n number of times.
:-

```
int main (void) {



int n, number, i;
char word[1000];

scanf("%d", &n);

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%d %s", &number, &word);

    printf("Player %d's record: %s\n", number, word);
    printf("Player %d's batting average is\n", number);
}   


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

my output is...

```
2
12 harambe
Player 12's record: harambe
Player 12's batting average is
13 Muhammad
Player 13's record: Muhammad
Player 13's batting average is
Press any key to continue . .
```

I'm trying to make it into:-

```
2
12 harambe
13 Muhammad

player 12's record: harambe
player 12's batting average is

player 13's record: Muhammad
player 13's batting average is
press any key to continue...
```

so AFTER i `scanf` my inputs, all at once BOTH player's records are brought up in one printf statement, this printf will scale with how high n goes up to, in this situation it's only 2, but if i put in 5, it should print 5 different players at once
.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Why are you printing a string as an integer? Using the wrong format leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for your "question" I recommend you [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *arrays* and *structures*. Then it's easy to have *two* loops.

Comment: Pick pick a language, either `C` or `C++`.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: You allocate arrays by malloc.

Comment: apologies, this is my first time using stackoverflow, I'm not sure what you mean by I didn't ask a question? and I'm a beginner in c, i'm currently taking a introductory level class in college, also i fixed the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can creates an array dynamically by `malloc` according to the input `n`.

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct player {
    int number;
    char name[64];
} Player;

int main(void){
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    Player *recs = malloc(n * sizeof(Player));
    if(recs == NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(2 != scanf("%d %63[^\n]%*c", &recs[i].number, recs[i].name)){
            printf("invalid input.\ninput again!\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n'); //clear input
            --i;
        }
    }
    puts("");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Player %d's record: %s\n", recs[i].number, recs[i].name);
        printf("Player %d's batting average is \n", recs[i].number);
    }
    free(recs);
    return 0;
}
```